# Deleting SQL datarow from a table swipes position of first and second row in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

adding updating everything is fine even delete command is working but the strange part is after executing del command from vb.net application it swipes the position of `EMPLOYEE_ID`AND `NAME`it shows normally in `datagridview`after adding or updating but specifically after deleting the record position of these to column changes until I stop the application and re run the entire project for debugging

```
     Dim con As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user=root; password=Masoom1; database=airtech_db; convert zero datetime=true;")
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    Dim DR As MySqlDataReader
    Dim SQL_CMD_TXT As String
  SQL_CMD_TXT = "DELETE FROM `employees` WHERE (`EMPLOYEE_ID` ='" &
            EMPLOYEE_DEL_FRM.DEL_ID_TXT.Text & "');  SELECT * FROM `employees`;"
        EMPLOYEE_DEL_FRM.Controls.Add(OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW)
        With OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW
            .Size = New Size(587, 242)
            .Location = New Size(221, 171)
        End With
 Try
        'DB CMD EXECUTION
        con.Open()
        With cmd
            sql = SQL_CMD_TXT
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = sql
        End With
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        'Command for datagridview object
        With OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW
            .DataSource = dt
            'Scroll to the last row.
            .Name = "MYDATAGRIDVIEW"
            .FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = .RowCount - 1
        End With
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim MEB = MessageBox.Show("ERROR FOR SQL CMD EXECUTION SECTION-" & ex.Message,
                                  "SQL CMD EXECUTION", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

attaching the normal and after delete result in images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILs4g.jpg)

Comment: I have no idea what you just said. Do you mean "swap" rather than "swipe"?

Comment: oh m really sorry yes i mean swap

Comment: dear  jmcilhinney please open the image attached https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILs4g.jpg

Comment: yes that worked buddy thaanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understood your problem, but your problem could that the datagridview generates the columns automatically. See: [DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns?view=netframework-4.8)

Instead of doing `SELECT * FROM` is would better to select just the fields you need. If you add more fields to your table in the future, the columns in the datagridview may be displaced because they are in no particular order.

Rather than add the datagridview to your form at runtime:

```
EMPLOYEE_DEL_FRM.Controls.Add(OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW)
```

I would add it directly in the form layout (so you can see it at design time), and then customize it, bind each column to a database field. The appearance of the grid will be more predictable. Here is a small guide: [How to bind datatable/list to datagridview with headers?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10667fb3-9bf4-44be-8177-d48b5a779389/how-to-bind-datatablelist-to-datagridview-with-headers?forum=winformsdatacontrols)
Relying on `AutoGenerateColumns` is not a great idea, because this will show all columns (usually not desirable) and not necessarily in the order that you want.

Other remarks:

Records can be edited or deleted directly in the datagridview, by simply selecting one or more rows, and pressing the Del key. Then just invoke the DataAdapter to commit the changes to the database. You should not even be doing `DELETE FROM`. Just let the user use the datagridview. The benefit is that if the user makes a mistake, you can roll back changes because you are using a datatable. Here you are deleting immediately and without warning.

---

Don't do stuff like:

```
  SQL_CMD_TXT = "DELETE FROM `employees` WHERE (`EMPLOYEE_ID` ='" &
            EMPLOYEE_DEL_FRM.DEL_ID_TXT.Text & "');  SELECT * FROM `employees`;"
```

---

Use **parameterized queries instead**, this code is **insecure** and will choke on single quotes or special characters (try it !). Here is a simple example: [FAQ: How do I make a parameterized query in the database with VB.NET?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bdf8b71-1cf1-41c0-848c-4fca2c9e1ea2/faq-how-do-i-make-a-parameterized-query-in-the-database-with-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral). Please use parameterized queries from now on, don't develop **bad habits** that will always **bite** you sooner or later. The security risk alone is too high.

---

Also I am wondering why you did **stacked queries**. It would better to separate the SELECT from the DELETE.

---

In this code variable `sql` is not needed:

```
With cmd
    sql = SQL_CMD_TXT
    .Connection = con
    .CommandText = sql
End With
```

Just use SQL_CMD_TXT directly. Otherwise it makes the code more difficult to follow.

Comment: "It would better to separate the SELECT from the DELETE." Why?

Comment: "It would better to separate the SELECT from the DELETE." Why? => make code more readable, separate functionality, isolate operations (in case of database error it may not be immediately obvious which statement failed). Also, not all database middleware will support stacked queries.

Comment: Yes, but single connection, single command. I believe this is supported by MySql. This is very common in MS Sql Server. How would your return the `ScopeIdentity()`? Or `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` in MySql?

Comment: To retrieve the ID after an insert, he should use the functions available from the MySQL Connector API he's using: [MySqlCommand.LastInsertedId Property](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_LastInsertedId.htm), while keeping in mind that the current connection will define the scope.